# group results of javascript map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I have a page on my Gatsby site that queries information for a number of businesses, including their address, city, and state, and that allows me to pass the data down to my component, in this case `LocationList`, and map over the results. I'm wondering if it's possible to split the results more precisely so that I can have the locations separated by a heading i.e. 'California', and below it all of the locations that are in California, or 'Arizona, and below it all the locations in Arizona? I'm building in Gatsby/GraphQl, and I'll include all the code I think is necessary, but feel free to ask for more, or for clarification.

**locations.tsx**

```
/* eslint-disable react/display-name */
import React from 'react';

import useAxios from 'axios-hooks';
import { SEO } from 'components/seo/SEO';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

import { LocationList } from './locations/location-list/_LocationList';
import { Map } from './locations/map/_Map';

export default (props: any) => {
  const document = props.data.allPrismicLocator.edges[0];
  if (!document) return null;

  const dealers = props.data.allMysqlDealers.edges;
  if (!dealers) return null;

  const [{ data, loading }] = useAxios(`${process.env.GATSBY_API_ENDPOINT}`);

  return (
    <>
      <SEO
        title={document.node.data.meta_title}
        desc={document.node.data.meta_description}
        banner={document.node.data.social_image.url}
      />
      <Map data={data} document={document.node.data} />
      <LocationList data={dealers} loading={loading} />
    </>
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
  query LocatorQuery {
    allPrismicLocator {
      edges {
        node {
          data {
            meta_title
            meta_description
            copy {
              text
            }
            theme
            location {
              latitude
              longitude
            }
            social_image {
              url
              dimensions {
                height
                width
              }
              alt
            }
            page_title {
              text
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    allMysqlDealers(sort: { fields: state, order: ASC }) {
      edges {
        node {
          subdomain
          address
          state
          zip
          city
          facebook
          yelp
          houzz
          phone
          name
          hrs_sun
          hrs_sat
          hrs_mf
          meta_geo_position
          owner
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

**_LocationList.tsx**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

import { Heading } from 'components/heading/Heading';
import { Link } from 'components/link/Link';
import { Container } from 'containers/container/Container';
import { Section } from 'containers/section/Section';
import { SelectedDealer } from 'contexts/dealers-context/DealersContext';
import { formatPhoneNumber } from 'utils/formatPhone';

import s from './LocationList.scss';

interface LocationListProps {
  loading: boolean;
  data: any;
}

export const LocationList = ({ data }: LocationListProps) => {
  const { changeDealer } = useContext(SelectedDealer);

  return (
    <Section>
      <Container>
        <div className={s.list}>
          {data &&
            data.map((dealer: any) => {
              const info = {
                name: dealer.node.name,
                phone: dealer.node.phone,
                location: dealer.node.city.toLowerCase() + '-' + dealer.node.state.toLowerCase(),
                hours: {
                  sunday: dealer.node.hrs_sun,
                  weekdays: dealer.node.hrs_mf,
                  saturday: dealer.node.hrs_sat,
                },
                socials: {
                  facebook: dealer.node.facebook,
                  yelp: dealer.node.yelp,
                  houzz: dealer.node.houzz,
                },
              };
              console.log(info);
              return (
                <div className={s.dealer} key={`dealer-item-${dealer.node.name}`}>
                  <div className={s.dealer__info}>
                    <Heading tag="h2" className={s.name}>
                      {dealer.node.name}
                    </Heading>
                    <span className={s.address}>{dealer.node.address}</span>
                    <span className={s.city}>
                      {dealer.node.city}, {dealer.node.state} {dealer.node.zip}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div className={s.dealer__contact}>
                    <span className={s.email}>{dealer.email}</span>
                    <span className={s.phone}>{formatPhoneNumber(dealer.node.phone)}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className={s.dealer__select}>
                    <Link to="/" className={s.button} onClick={() => changeDealer(info)}>
                      Select Location
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      </Container>
    </Section>
  );
};
```

Comment: just sort dealers data by state, then use `.map()` to create new dataset with additional 'state' level (create new node when state differs) ... then pass data into list component ... sort by cities before or inside list component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this figured out. I changed my query, using the built in `group` field, and grouped the nodes by state:

```
 allMysqlDealers {
  group(field: state) {
    edges {
      node {
        address
        city
        facebook
        houzz
        hrs_mf
        hrs_sat
        hrs_sun
        name
        page_title
        phone
        state
        subdomain
        yelp
        zip
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returned `edges` for each state, with their nodes.

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMysqlDealers": {
      "group": [
        {
          "edges": [
            {
              "node": {
                "subdomain": "phoenix",
                "address": "15475 N. Greenway Hayden Loop, Ste. B-14",
                "state": "AZ",
                "zip": "85260",
                "city": "Scottsdale ",
                "facebook": "",
                "yelp": "",
                "houzz": "",
                "phone": "480-405-3378",
                "name": "x Desert Sky Doors and Closets",
                "hrs_sun": "Closed",
                "hrs_sat": "10:00 am to 4:00 pm",
                "hrs_mf": "9:00 am to 5:00 pm",
                "page_title": "One Day Doors & Closets"
              }
            },
            {
              "node": {
                "subdomain": "arizona",
                "address": "\"SHOWROOM COMING SOON\"",
                "state": "AZ",
                "zip": "85345",
                "city": "Phoenix",
                "facebook": "",
                "yelp": "",
                "houzz": "",
                "phone": "",
                "name": "x Artela Doors & Closets",
                "hrs_sun": "Closed",
                "hrs_sat": "By Appointment",
                "hrs_mf": "9:00 am - 5:30 pm",
                "page_title": "Artela Doors & Closets"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in my component, I was able to map through them, like so...

```
const document = props.data.allMysqlDealers.group;
  if (!document) return null;

{document.map((groups: any, index: number) => {
          const state = groups.edges[0].node.state.trim();

          const stateName = convertRegion(state, toName);

          return (
            <Fragment key={`dealer-group-${index}`}>
              <Heading tag="h2" className={s.stateName}>{stateName}</Heading>
              <div className={s.row}>
                {groups.edges.map((dealer: any) => {
                  const now = new Date();
                  const days = formatHours(dealer.node);
                  const today = days[now.getDay()];
                  const todaysHours = `Today's Hours - ${today}`;

                  const info = formatInfo(dealer.node);

                  return (
                    <div className={s.dealer} key={`dealer-${dealer.node.name}`}>
                      <div className={s.dealer__info}>
                        <Heading tag="h2" className={s.name}>
                          {dealer.node.name}
                        </Heading>
                        <span>{todaysHours}</span>
                        <span className={s.address}>{dealer.node.address}</span>
                        <span className={s.city}>
                          {dealer.node.city}, {dealer.node.state} {dealer.node.zip}
                        </span>
                        <span className={s.email}>{dealer.email}</span>
                        <span className={s.phone}>{formatPhoneNumber(dealer.node.phone)}</span>
                      </div>

                      <Button
                        href={'/dealers/' + formatUrl(dealer.node.city + ' ' + dealer.node.state)}
                        className={s.button}
                        onClick={() => changeDealer(info)}
                      >
                        Choose Location
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
```

...and it all worked wonderfully.